# Best updated alternative to Linux in a Nutshell?

Tags: linux, reference, books

I'm old and forgetful.  I've been using my handy-dandy copy of *Unix in a Nutshell* for years to look up syntax and such.

I decided it's time to update it (it's nearly 30 years old at this point) and switch to a Linux version.  However, it appears that O'Reilly has transitioned to a mostly online, skillshare-type company and hasn't updated *Linux in a Nutshell* in more than a decade.  In addition, it now covers stuff like "virtualization, wireless network management, and revision control with git", none of which I'm interested in a command reference.

So before I shell out $30-65 for an outdated reference filled with stuff I don't need, are there any better alternatives?  I'm looking for a physical book (because I'm old) rather than a PDF or other online reference.  I'd like something that lists commands with the syntax, options, and maybe a couple of short examples.  The version I have has useful chapters on sed, awk, test, and pattern matching (regex), so that would be good too.

I'll probably pick up a used copy to start with but if there's something more recent or better, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: At the time when Linux in a Nutshell came out, Git wasn't a thing. I just checked, it covered SVN

Answer (score 4):

The closest modern equivalent to *Linux in a Nutshell* that I know of is [William Shotts’ *The Linux Command Line*](https://nostarch.com/tlcl2); its second edition was published in 2019. It covers most of the topics you mention; the main exception is AWK.

The author has released the book under a Creative Commons license, [it is available free of charge in electronic form](https://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) (which isn’t directly relevant for this question, but helpful for other readers and also allows you to check the contents in detail before purchase).

Comment: That looks like a good book but I'm looking for more of a reference -- man pages in a book, if you will.   I'm certainly no Linux expert (COBOL programmer by trade) but I've been working with Linux, including writing lots of scripts, for 30+ years.  I just forget the syntax and options for commands I don't use all the time.

Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: RE: *"I just forget the syntax and options for commands I don't use all the time"* - that's true for everybody.  And it's what `man` is for.   Nobody actually remembers all the options for all available commands, we might remember the stuff we use all the time but for everything else (and when we want to be sure that we're not forgetting something important) we just look them up when we need them....and instead of slowly searching through a physical book, `man [command-name]` gives the details instantly.  Even better, man pages are usually updated when the program is, or shortly after.

Comment: Also useful: make a directory to keep plain-text (or markdown) notes about things you learn, and little example snippets of code and the like.  When you figure out something that's difficult, write a note about it *in your own words*.   Just a quick summary to jog your memory can be enough but IMO & IME, it's often best to write as if you're teaching it to someone else as doing that pretty much forces you to organise and consolidate your thoughts about a topic, and that often leads to even better understanding.

Comment: @cas - I get that that's what man is for but for my personal workflow, a reference book with bookmarks and post-its works best.  I do use man but I've just found that a physical book works best.  It lives in a little basket attached below my desk and takes me almost no time to pull out, open to the desired page, and continue, all without losing my place on-screen.  Maybe it's because I'm old (been writing code for more than 40 years) but it's just what works for me.

Comment: @cas - I also refer to (steal from) previous scripts I've written constantly; they serve as my notes most of the time.  It's not so much a lack of understanding of what a command does or even which command to use, it's remembering the syntax.  I've used so many operating systems and programming languages over the years that sometimes I mix them up.  8^/

Comment: For AWK, the book by Aho et al and the official manual of GAWK are good